# Current knowledge of Higgs

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

What is the current knowledge about the Higgs field after its discovery in the LHC? Does it exactly mimic the standard model Higgs? Does this knowledge rules out the possibility of other Higgs particles beyond the standard model like triplet higgs model etc?

Comment: I believe the LHC is about to switch back on, which is now venturing literally into the unknown and I don't think we are looking for anything specific this time around (not sure on that?). More like fishing in a big lake, hope we get something or anything new.

Comment: @Dave We're still trying to get more precise measurements on particles we've already discovered - but that's as far as the SM goes. We're also trying to test theories of physics beyond the SM, in particular seeing if we can find any SUSY particle or magnetic monopole, developing our understanding of CP violation, and checking if the Higgs is really what it's supposed to be (i.e. is there only one Higgs boson? Is it an elementary particle?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is extremely vast. Here is a quick answer:

- Does it exactly mimic the standard model Higgs?

Within experimental errors, the answer is yes (so far). The couplings tested so far (directly or via quantum loops) show that they are proportional to the mass of the fermions as expected by the standard model (SM). Only heavy fermions have reasonably been tested: $b,t,\tau$. The couplings to gauge bosons $Z,W,\gamma$ are also compatible with the SM.
The spin and CP numbers are compatible with SM expectation even if statistic accumulated during the run1 (which lasted 2 years) is not large enough to prove it with a $5 \sigma$ confidence level. 
One important thing to be tested with run2 data (started reasonably in May-June at 13 TeV): the self coupling of the higgs boson (to itself). We estimate that by the end of run2 (~2023), the trilinear coupling will be tested: $H \to HH$. The quadrilinear coupling $H\to HHH$ (the famous $\lambda$ in the Higgs scale potential) is probably beyond the reach of LHC run2.

- Does this knowledge rules out the possibility of other Higgs particles beyond the standard model like triplet higgs model etc?

The minimal supersymmetric model (MSSM) is now severely constrained. The whole phase space is however not totally ruled out. With run2 data, one might discover some heavy super-particles or deviation of the SM coupling to low mass fermions for instance: $H \to \mu\mu$. But if so, scenarios beyond MSSM are probable.